# No Android SDK found. Try setting the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable. android studio flutter build on windows

Tags: android, windows, flutter

recieved this error on android studio flutter app apk generation..[!] No Android SDK found. Try setting the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable.
Process finished with exit code 1

How do I fix this I am running on windows

Answer (score 0):

You must follow **every** step in [the official documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows). Do not rely on third-party "install videos" or instructions given within a training course. Those can become outdated over time.